# Calculus Optimization problem

Tags: calculus

[image: sketch]
Help with the problem??

The cost of building the pipeline is $\$3$ million per mile in the water, and $\$4$ million per mile on land. Hence, the cost of the pipeline depends on the location of point $P$. where it meets shore. What would be the most economical route of the pipeline?

Comment: What have you tried?  No figure is attached to this problem, but I imagine you mean that the offshore facility is 5 miles  from the perpendicular to the coast which runs through the refinery.

Comment: http://s3.amazonaws.com/answer-board-image/86e1a638-a4c1-42a5-a153-e4cfcf058280.bmp image can be found here

Comment: I honestly don't know how to go about this.. I was thinking of using the pythagorean theorem and constructing another right triangle below P, but i don't really know..

Comment: Ah, so I imagined incorrectly.  The total distance between the facility and the refinery is 5 miles.

Comment: Can you calculate the distance  I thought was 5?  That is, can you calculate the horizontal distance between the facility and the refinery?

Comment: For the distance between A and B parallel to the shore line, imagine a _single_ large right triangle with the 5 miles as its hypotenuse.  The total distance perpendicular to that between A and B is 3 miles.  What then must be the distance along the shoreline between A and B? (The red dashed lines are, in a sense, a "folded-up" version of that big triangle.)

Comment: Just to say: the required optimization problem looks quite messy via calculus.  Not at all difficult numerically and perhaps that is what is intended.  Absent the price differential we'd just take a straight line, but I don't see a geometric analog here (which doesn't prove there isn't one!)

Comment: For the rest of dealing with such a problem, if you're not sure how to continue, search this site using "pipeline", "optimization" : this problem turns up from time to time.

Comment: @lulu The "geometric analog" is that of a light-refraction problem between two media.  The calculations can be kept from getting too messy by "squaring away" radicals whenever possible.  (Implicit differentiation is of limited help because of the cost factors, since it's not just a distance-minimization, alas.)

Comment: @RecklessReckoner Is that principle clean enough to construct the "break point" geometrically?

Comment: @lulu  Well, trigonometrically, using "Snell's Law" (a matter which turns up in at least a couple of the related posts).

Comment: @RecklessReckoner.  Makes sense.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**Physics Approach:**

In this solution, all units are ignored.  Consider an imaginary wave that travels along the water's surface at the speed $v_a:=\frac{1}{3}$ and on the surface of the land at the speed $v_b:=\frac{1}{4}$ .  The total time it travels along the polygonal line $APB$ is $t( P):=\frac{AP}{v_a}+\frac{BP}{v_b}=3\cdot AP+4\cdot BP$.  By Fermat's Principle of Least Time, the wave will take the time minimizing route.  If $Q$ is the minimizing point, then by Snell's Law, we must have $\frac{\sin\left(\theta_a\right)}{\sin\left(\theta_b\right)}=\frac{v_a}{v_b}=\frac{4}{3}$, if $\theta_a$ and $\theta_b$ is the angle $AQ$ and $BQ$ make with the normal line to the water-land boundary.

Let $C$ and $D$ be the feet of the perpendiculars from $A$ and $B$ to the water-land boundary.  We have $CD=4$.  Let $x:=CQ$.  Then, $$\sin\left(\theta_a\right)=\cos(AQC)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+4}}\text{ and }\sin\left(\theta_b\right)=\cos(BQD)=\frac{4-x}{\sqrt{(4-x)^2+1}}\,.$$
From $\frac{\sin\left(\theta_a\right)}{\sin\left(\theta_b\right)}=\frac{4}{3}$, we have
$$\frac{3x}{\sqrt{x^2+4}}=\frac{4(4-x)}{\sqrt{(4-x)^2+1}}\,.$$
The rest is just as in Michael Galuza's solution, where we obtain $x\approx 3.178466628$.

Answer (score 2):

Using the figure in the post, let us define the coordinates of the points : $A (0,2)$ , $P (0,x)$, $B (d,-1)$.

Now, for computing $d$, the square of the distance between points $A$ and $B$ is given by $$D_{AB}^2=(x_A-x_B)^2+(y_A-y_B)^2=(0-d)^2+(2+1)^2=d^2+9=5^2=25$$ which makes $d=4$. Similarly $$D_{AP}^2=(x_A-x_P)^2+(y_A-y_P)^2=(0-x)^2+(2-0)^2=x^2+4$$ $$D_{BP}^2=(x_B-x_P)^2+(y_B-y_P)^2=(4-x)^2+(-1-0)^2=1+(4-x)^2$$ So, the cost function is $$C=3 \sqrt{x^2+4}+4\sqrt{1+(4-x)^2}$$ and this is what we need to minimize.

The derivative of $C$ with respect to $x$ is given by $$C'=\frac{3 x}{\sqrt{x^2+4}}-\frac{4 (4-x)}{\sqrt{1+(4-x)^2}}$$ Uisng $C'=0$, we can then rewrite  $$\frac{\sqrt{1+(4-x)^2}}{\sqrt{x^2+4}}=\frac{4 (4-x)}{3x}$$ Squaring, reducing to same denominator and simplifying leads to $$7 x^4-56 x^3+167 x^2-512 x+1024=0$$ which is not pleasant since it is a quartic. Plotting it between $x=0$ and $x=4$ which are our bounds shows that the root is close to $x=3$. So, we can start Newton method using $x_0=3$ and the iterates will be given by $$x_{n+1}=\frac {21 x_n^4-112 x_n^3+167 x_n^2-1024}{28 x_n^3-168 x_n^2+334 x_n-512}$$ that is to say $3.17293$, $3.17846$ , $3.17847$ which is the solution for six significant figures.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A=(0,2)$. Let's find coordinates of $B$. We have a right triangle with hypothenuse $5$ and side $2 + 1 = 3$; so, another side is $\sqrt{5^2 - 3^2} = 4$ and $B = (4,-1)$. Now,
$$
AP = \sqrt{2^2 + x^2},\enspace BP = \sqrt{(4-x)^2 + 1^2}.
$$
Total cost is
$$
C(x) = 3\cdot AP + 4\cdot PB = 3\sqrt{\strut x^2 + 4} + 4\sqrt{\strut 1 + (4-x)^2}.
$$
We need to minimize $C(x)$. Find derivative:
$$
\frac{dC}{dx} = \frac{3x}{\sqrt{x^2+4}} - \frac{4(4-x)}{\sqrt{1 + (4-x)^2}}.
$$
This equation simplified to
$$
7x^4 - 56x^3 + 167x^2 - 512x + 1024=0;
$$
(not so simpler, hm ;) it's better to solve it numerically:
$$
x \approx 3.178466628,\enspace C(x) \approx 16.44279212\\
x\approx 4.968627813,\enspace C(x)\approx 21.63697470
$$
So, optimal $x$ is $\approx 3.178466628$.

As you can see, this problem is analogous to problem in optics: light passing through a boundary between two different isotropic media, and asked to find light way. We've got Snell's law!

Answer (score 0):

The total cost is $C=3AP+4PB$.

Once you notice that the figure may be inscribed in a $3/4/5$ triangle, you can write $AP=\sqrt {x^{2}+4} $ and $PB=\sqrt {(4-x)^{2}+1}$.

Therefore, $C(x)=3\sqrt {x^{2}+4}+4\sqrt {(4-x)^{2}+1}$ which has its minimum at $x=3.17$ good to two places.

[function http://www4a.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP464820a1ahb704g18121000065437e5daa93367a?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=57&w=433.&h=197.&cdf=Coordinates&cdf=Tooltips](http://www4a.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP464820a1ahb704g18121000065437e5daa93367a?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=57&w=433.&h=197.&cdf=Coordinates&cdf=Tooltips)